# Product still listed as enabled in Antivirusproduct class even though uninstalled 5 days ago

Tags: windows-10, security, powershell, security-center

I uninstalled F-Secure 5 days ago and have restarted/powered down this device several times since. It seems that either the data returned by this query is outdated (and a refresh/reload may solve the issue, if at all possible) or that Windows truly believes the F-Secure product is still installed and enabled.

```
Function ConvertTo-NPHex
{
    Param([int]$Number)"0x{0:x}" -f $Number
}

$Products = @();
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -ClassName Antivirusproduct -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object{

    $hex = ConvertTo-NPHex $_.ProductState; 
    $mid = $hex.Substring(3,2);
    $end = $hex.Substring(5);

    $Products += [ordered]@{
        DisplayName = $_.DisplayName;
        Enabled = $( 
            If( $mid -match "00|01" ){ 
                $False 
            }Else{ 
                $True 
            } 
        );
        UpToDate = $( 
            If($end -eq "00"){ 
                $True 
            }Else{ 
                $False 
            } 
        );
        Updated = $( (Get-Date -Date $_.Timestamp).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") )
    }

};
Return $Products | ConvertTo-Json;
```

**Output from snippet above:**

```
[
    {
        "DisplayName":  "F-Secure SAFE",
        "ProductState":  270336,
        "Enabled":  true,
        "UpToDate":  true,
        "Updated":  "2020-06-17T08:09:16Z"
    },
    {
        "DisplayName":  "Windows Defender",
        "ProductState":  393472,
        "Enabled":  false,
        "UpToDate":  true,
        "Updated":  "2020-06-17T07:59:53Z"
    },
    {
        "DisplayName":  "ESET Security",
        "ProductState":  266240,
        "Enabled":  true,
        "UpToDate":  true,
        "Updated":  "2020-06-22T12:28:56Z"
    }
]
```

I am absolutely certain that F-Secure is not installed. Not only did I remove it manually, but it's also not visible in the Security Center UI, not under installed programs and not detected by a PowerShell script that looks through the registry for installed programs. This device is also not listed in my F-Secure web administration console, so I know it's uninstalled.

**Expected situation:**

- F-Secure isn't listed at all (it's not installed)
- Windows Defender is listed and not enabled
- ESET is listed and enabled

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to 'force' a refresh of this class?
- Is it known when this class is 'organically' updated?
- Any tacit knowledge as to why the product is still in the response?

Comment: "remove it manually" how? Antiviruses often need specific uninstallers rather than simple Add/Remove - see https://www.f-secure.com/gb-en/home/support/tools

Comment: I'm not sure you're correct, most commercial AV products can be removed safely and completely using the products packaged uninstaller. Even the page you have linked me to to states "Use this tool only as a last resort if you are not able to remove the product through the normal uninstallation method."

Comment: You didn't say what you used, you only said you removed it manually. Have you tried the 'special case uninstaller'? If not, why not? If so, what happened?

Comment: I have not tried the special case uninstaller because the product is not on my device. The issue is not with the antivirus product, its with the AntiVirusProduct class in the SecurityCenter. To move past this, I have run the 'special case' uninstaller as you have requested and it 'succeeded'. I have run my code again and Windows still believes the product is active. This is an issue with Windows, not F-Secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to delete it from the class:

Via UI:

- run `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wbemtest.exe` as administrator
- click on `connect`
- write `root\SecurityCenter2` in the Namespace field
- click `connect`
- click `enum instances`
- in the field `Enter superclass name` enter `AntivirusProduct` and click OK
- delete the instance where the GUID matches the one returned by `Get-CimInstance`

Via cmd (as admin)

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 PATH AntiVirusProduct WHERE instanceGuid='Insert the GUID' DELETE
```

replace `Insert the GUID` with your GIUD e.g `{88AE6B46-DC3C-455A-A21B-085F285A3546}` (with `{}` and everything)

Guide taken from https://community.absolute.com/s/article/The-Anti-Malware-Report-lists-multiple-products-when-only-one-is-installed

Comment: Thanks for offering a solution, I'm actually more interested in the root cause and a more native solution. With 1000's of devices under management it's not ideal to manually detect and resolve this issue. I was hoping someone would be aware of a 'refresh' method, or approach that can have the device automatically reassess its products

Comment: I would say this is a bug in the security product. They should register and un-register with Security Center.

Comment: @Arbiter well even if you have 1000s of machines under management, you can check if f-secure is installed through the registry on each computer - then check if wmi still shows f-secure and if so delete the instance. That's kind of a refresh. And you can do this from one single server that has access to all other machines. if you're interested i can code it quickly for you